# How to exclude some files and directories from sonar coverage report - react, typescript project using jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, sonarqube, code-coverage, enzyme

So I have `Create React App` with typescript template. I have also integrated sonarqube with it.

First When I ran sonar report with below configuration,

```
scanner(
      {
        serverUrl: "http://localhost:9000",
        token: "*****",
        options: {
          ...
          "sonar.tests": "./src",
          "sonar.test.inclusions": "**/*.test.tsx,**/*.test.ts, **/*.js",
          "sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths": "coverage/lcov.info",
          "sonar.testExecutionReportPaths": "test-report.xml"
        },
      },
      () => process.exit()
    );
```

The result is as below,

as you can see, it includes following file which is fine.

[image]

Now I am changing sonar-scanner.js configuration as below,

```
const testExclusions = `./src/index.ts,./src/reportWebVitals.ts, ./src/core/constants/**/*,./src/core/interfaces/**/*`;


scanner(
  {
    serverUrl: "http://localhost:9000",
    token: "*****",
    options: {
      ...
      "sonar.tests": "./src",
      "sonar.test.inclusions": "**/*.test.tsx,**/*.test.ts, **/*.js",

      "sonar.test.exclusions": `${testExclusions}`  <<=== I don't know if this line plays any role.

      "sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths": "coverage/lcov.info",
      "sonar.testExecutionReportPaths": "test-report.xml"
    },
  },
  () => process.exit()
);
```

BUT again result is same. there is no change in the report.

Then, I introduced **jest** configuration in package.json as follow,

```
"test:report": "npm run test -- --watchAll=false --coverage --testResultsProcessor jest-sonar-reporter",

...
...

"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,tsx,ts}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts",
      "!src/reportWebVitals.ts",
      "!src/index.ts",
      "!src/core/constants/**/*",
      "!src/core/interfaces/**/*"
    ]
  }
```

and I ran `npm run test:report` and it generated new `test-report.xml` with below files,

[image]

as you can see, it doesn't cover excluded files/directories.

When I ran sonar-scanner again, I believed now it will not show excluded files/directories in sonar coverage report **but it is not the case yet**. **It is still including those files and directories**.

***What is wrong with this setup ?***

x

Comment: Have you tried to use this ```sonar.coverage.exclusions``` in sonar options

Comment: Not yet. let me try.

Comment: Looks like it is working... Testing with some more scenarios. Meanwhile you can post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes as follow,

**1)** For some reason, need to remove `./` before `src` as below,

```
const testExclusions = `src/index.ts,src/reportWebVitals.ts, src/core/constants/**/*,src/core/interfaces/**/*`
```

**2)** use: **sonar.coverage.exclusions** property in sonar options instead of  **sonar.test.exclusions**

```
"sonar.coverage.exclusions": `${testExclusions}`
```

**Optional**:

**3)** if you want to remove **jest** configuration from package.json. It is fine.